# How do I get rid of attribute error in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I want to turn a series of matplotlib figures into an animation. However, whatever I do, I always receive error. I use Enthought Canopy 1.6.2 and Python 2.7.13 on Windows 10.

I have tried using [videofig](https://github.com/bilylee/videofig/blob/master/videofig.py) package. While it was good, I could not manage to save the mp4 file. Also, I believe using the source directly, i.e., matplotlib animation package would be more versatile for future uses. I checked a few answers, including [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853680/animation-using-matplotlib-with-subplots-and-artistanimation), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212722/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-animate) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689665/how-am-i-able-to-import-matplotlib-without-an-error), yet none of them solved my problem.

The function I call is structured as follows.

```py
def some_plotter(self, path, start_value, image_array)
    some_unrelated_fig_functions()
    im=plt.savefig(path, animated=True)
    image_array.append([im])
    plt.close("all")
```

The main code is as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation
image_array=[]
while(something):
    some_obj.some_plotter(path, start_value, image_array)
fig = plt.figure()
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, image_array, interval=50, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)
```

I receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\kocac\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py", line 387, in process
>       proxy(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\kocac\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py", line 227, in **call**
>       return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\kocac\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1026, in _start
>       self._init_draw()
>     File "C:\Users\kocac\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1557, in _init_draw
>       artist.set_visible(False)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_visible'

I had more similar lines to this, yet updating Matplotlib, following the suggestion at [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689665/how-am-i-able-to-import-matplotlib-without-an-error) reduced the error lines to 4. Yet I cannot proceed any longer. Note that saved images are perfectly fine so I am probably not doing anything wrong in the image creation.

How can I get rid of these errors? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you cannot use `plt.close("all")` in the middle of your animation, but one cannot help you unless you provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is some code that we could copy/paste and run for ourselves

Comment: `plt.savefig` does not return anything useful, which can be animated. So if you print out `image_array` you should see a list of None. I would suggest to stick to the solutions you linked to.